# Como añadir un backslash en un String?

Tags: java, string, regex

Necesito añadir una "\" dentro de un string. Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
public class testClassADDBackslash {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F7977C&0&1200");

    for (int a=0; a<sb.length(); a++){
        if( sb.charAt(a) == '\\'){
           sb.insert(a, '\\');
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Necesito modificar esta String y añadirle otra '\' cuando se encuentre esta ocurrencia, ya que el valor de esta String va a ser guardado en una variable para usar en cmd. Como algunos ya sabréis, es necesario pasar estos valores con caracter de escape '\' para que el cmd los interprete correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe alguna manera simple de hacerlo? los métodos de `StringBuffer` parece que no son los adecuados para hacer esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
 "USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F7977C&0&1200"
      .replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
```

Ejemplo:

```
    String b = "USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F7977C&0&1200";
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(b.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\"));
```

Salida:

```
USB\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\6&9F7977C&0&1200
USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00\\6&9F7977C&0&1200
```

Como existe confusión porque funciona eso, lo explico:

`"\\\\"` aqui se usa par crear un `String` que contiene `\\`, porque `\\` es lo que se necesita en una regex para captar un `\`. Todo bien todavía? XD

`"\\\\\\\\"` produce un `String` que contiene `\\\\`. En el momento cuando este cadena de remplazo esta insertado en la cadena original en vez del `\`, se evalua de nuevo a `\\`. Así tenemos la cadena como corresponde.

Comment: Acabo de probar, cuando imprimo la String, sigue imprimiendo con una sola \ en vez de \\

Comment: te actualicé la respuesta con código comprobado incluyendo la salida. Que haces diferente?

Comment: Ahora si funciona, no se que habré hecho mal :? Esta es la respuesta, mil gracias!!

Comment: Lo que hiciste mál es confundirte no tomando en cuenta donde/cuantas veces la maquina virtual revalúa el codigo, así terminaste al fin donde empezaste. Por eso es recomendable de colocar un método y implementar un test.